# Git submodules - Changing branch brings changes from previous branch to current branch

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-submodules

I am working with submodules in Android studio. The problem is that switching to a different branch brings changes from old branch.

Let's say I have a module M in my app. I am currently working on branch B1. While on this branch I delete my module M and commit, then switch to branch B2. I notice that branch B2 too doesn't have module M. Why is this so? How do I make it such that the changes from one branch isn't carried to another on switching branches?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have recursive checkout enabled, you must run `git submodule update` after changing to a different commit. (If you do have it enabled, Git either literally runs `git submodule update` for you, in older Git versions, or does the equivalent with somewhat fewer process invocations, in the most recent ones.)